# How to plot $\frac{x + y - abs(x - y)}{2}$ in the opposite direction

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

I am studying this equation:

$$\frac{x + y - abs(x - y)}{2}$$

If I plotted it looks like this [Equation in 3D between [0 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxgax.png), a rectangular pyramid.

I wanted to plot the same shape but wanted it to be on the opposite side with the reverse of this function. [Like in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpmJK.png)

What will the equation of this shape be? or how to change the original equation so then I can generate the shape on the top right?

Comment: $-\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$?

Comment: I tried but it becomes negative. I still want the shape to be on the positive side, as shown in the figure

Comment: What do you mean by "the opposite side" ? Could you describe the basis of this pyramid ?

Comment: It's like turning the whole shape by 270 degrees. The base and everything else will be the same. Please see the photo attached that show how it should look like

Comment: If the corner is at $(a,b)$, then replace $x$ with $(a-x)$ and $y$ with $(b-y)$, giving you $$z = \frac{a - x + b - y - abs(a - x - b + y)}{2}$$and plot $x = a-1 \dots a$, $y = b - 1 \dots b$.

Comment: @BlabbotheVerbose thank you, that solved my problem, do you mind if I write it as a solution or do you wanna it as an answer?

Comment: @Sami: Do write your own answer, please!